# Calling allocator_traits::deallocate on a null pointer

Tags: c++, memory-management

If `Allocator` conforms to the standard library allocator interface, is it safe to call `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::deallocate` with a null pointer? I know it is when `Allocator` is `std::allocator` (because it ultimately defers to `delete`) but what if `Allocator` is a client provided class? Do I have to do an explicit check? `cppreference.com`'s article on the [Allocator concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) doesn't list any such guarantees so I think the answer is "yes" but I wanted to be sure.

To give a bit of motivation for the question, I'm imagining a use case where a variable `p` is supposed to hold a pointer to the buffer (and is initially set to `nullptr`), but for some reason the buffer was never allocated in the first place so `p` remains a null pointer.

Comment: You mean that pointer to storage is nullptr AND number of objects is > 0?

Comment: Does the answer change depending on whether the number of objects is zero or not?

Comment: My impression has been that if the allocator under question may return nullptr to allocate then nullptr is valid argument to deallocate as well. However I can't imagine why it returns nullptr if the number of objects is > 0.

Comment: I'm imagining a use case where `allocate` didn't return the null pointer in question. Instead, `allocate` was never called, so the variable holding a pointer to the buffer is still null. I added this to the question.

Comment: That is illegal usage of deallocate since "preconditon: p shall be a value returned by an earlier call to allocate that has not been invalidated by
an intervening call to deallocate"
.

Comment: Good point. I want to keep the question alive for a bit longer because the actual standard (rather than `cppreference.com`) may require accounting for null pointers explicitly.

Comment: I quoted actual standard § 17.6.3.5 table 29. Allocator requirements

Comment: Oh okay, if you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually follow up question: what if `p` is null and number of objects is 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, `std::allocator<T>::deallocate(T* p, std::size_t)` does *not* call `delete p`. Instead it calls `operator delete(p)` according to 23.10.9.1 [allocator.members] paragraph 7. Instead, the requirement in paragraph 5 of the same paragraph states that `p` shall have been obtained from `std::allocator<T>::allocate()`. This function cannot return a null pointer, i.e., `std::allocator<T>::deallocate()` does not accept null points. It would be surprising if the allocator concept allows passing null pointers as `std::allocator<T>` wouldn't model that concept.

The allocator concept in Table 31 likewise requires that the argument to `a.deallocate(p)` was obtained from `a.allocate()`. Since the specification of `a.allocate(n)` always returns enough memory for `n` objects (the only failure indication is via an exception) it follows that `a.deallocate()` is not expected to cope with a null pointer.

The question was about `allocator_traits<...>::deallocate()`. However, according to 23.10.8.2 [allocator.traits.members] paragraph 3 this function merely delegates to the `deallocate()` function of the allocator. That is, a null pointer is not a valid argument there, either.

Comment: When the number objects given is 0 then what Allocator::allocate returns is unspecified. That "unspecified" means valid value that is left up to implementation (or custom allocator) to specify.  Can not it be nullptr?

Comment: @ÖöTiib: an implementation of an allocator can choose to use `nullptr` as its representation for a zero sized sequence of objects. However, it is not guaranteed that it will do so, i.e., users cannot make any assumption that `nullptr` is a valid representation.